# R - Named numeric vectors and ggplot2 bar chart

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm trying to produce a bar chart using ggplot2 - but having issues.

Essentially, I want to generate a horiztonal bar chart, with:

- geographical locations on the Y axis;
- count of population along the x axis.

However, I have a dataframe with the following structure:

```
       data.frame(Park = c("Northumberland","South Downs","Dartmoor"), 
       count = c(22.5,24.4,26.0))
```

And as expected, the population count is plotting straight onto the x axis, while I want it to plot on the y axis.

Any ideas?

Sorry this is a simple question.

[image]

Comment: It would help if you shared the ggplot code that you have tried that isn't working. (In your question, not in a comment.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`coord_flip` to swap x and y axes.

```
library(ggplot2)
dat <- data.frame(Park = c("Northumberland","South Downs","Dartmoor"), 
                  count = c(22.5,24.4,26.0))

ggplot(dat, aes(x=Park, weight=count)) + geom_bar() + coord_flip()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `geom_col`:

```
df = data.frame(Park = c("Northumberland","South Downs","Dartmoor"), 
           count = c(22.5,24.4,26.0))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = Park, y = count)) +
  geom_col()
```

To use `geom_bar`, you need to specify `stat = "identity"` to be able to supply a `y` variable:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = Park, y = count)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip()
```

Comment: Hi, I've added a photo above for clarity. To be sure, I want the x axis to be a generic scale and the y axis to be the values for the geographical locations, but with the tick marks indicating the names of the locations.